# 'We Americans like baseball' or 'Us Americans...'?

Tags: pronouns

Which one is correct?

- 'We Americans like baseball,' or
- 'Us Americans like baseball'?

Why would you prefer one over the other? I'm thinking of a situation where people from different countries are talking about differences in their cultures. Thanks!

**Edit**. The [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184843/we-all-teachers-or-all-us-teachers) linked as a possible duplicate is more related to the expression *all of us* than to *we* vs *us* in the context of my question.

Comment: That is an apposition. Also: subject verb predicate. us cannot be a subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["We all teachers" or "All us teachers"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184843/we-all-teachers-or-all-us-teachers)

Comment: Both are pretty rare in spoken language these days, to be honest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not really, but thanks for the reference. I think James K answer is more clear than the answers in that thread.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both will be heard, but "we" is better.

> We Americans like change. It is at once our weakness and our strength. [W. Somerset Maugham](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/697095-we-americans-like-change-it-is-at-once-our-weakness)

> The book then corroborates a story that we Americans like to tell ourselves [Maxine Swann](https://4columns.org/swann-maxine/a-word-for-love)

Examples of "Us Americans" are harder to find, because Google interprets it as an abbreviation of "United States Americans".  However, here are some examples with "Canadians":

> Us Canadians like to call it the TSN turning point. [twitter](https://twitter.com/datkeed/status/1463521864798683148)

> As you probably expect, there is a wide range of topics us Canadians like to discuss... [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-topics-do-Canadians-like-to-talk-about)

You will notice that there is a big difference in the quality of these sources.  The use of "We Americans" comes from writers with a reputation, whereas the use of "Us Americans" is in casual internet postings.

The formal and "correct" usage is "We Americans".

Comment: @numberfive To elaborate: "We" is grammatically correct in these examples because it's the *subject*. Remove "Americans" from the examples and the choice is clear: "We like basketball" vs "Us like basketball." But if it were the object, "us" would be the correct choice: "Basketball is important to us Americans." A completely separate topic is whether it's *preferable* to be strictly correct; you might "prefer" the non-grammatical choice because you're in a context in which it's the established idiomatic practice.

Comment: (JamesK, might be nice to edit to include the grammatical basis of *why* "we" is the right choice here, and to avoid implying that it's always the right choice in all constructions, and I can delete my comment. Unless you disagree.)

Comment: But, @Andy, I dislike that explanation.  The subject isn't "We", it is "We Americans",  and there is no reason why English must use the same pronoun form for "We" on its own as in combination with another word.  It would be just as logical for "Us" to be the only correct pronoun to be used. Similarly I dislike the "logic" of "You and I" instead of "You and me" or "Me and you" as the subject of a noun.  You can make rules in which "Me and you" is logical and correct.

Comment: @JamesK Well, the beauty of language is that you can like or dislike any of it, and indeed can use whatever constructions you want. You did ask what's *correct*, though, and if you choose constructions based on personal preference, your hearers might not have the same preference. There's nothing magical about "correct" grammar; it's all based on fairly arbitrary opinions and whims, but it's the opinions and whims that entire societies agree on over time. Meanwhile...

Comment: Meanwhile, I would respectfully argue that yes, the pronoun *we* is the subject, and that "Americans" is an [appositive](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html). Ultimately, the nominative and accusative inflection of pronouns isn't a matter of personal opinion (though accepting such a usage can be).

Comment: I wonder where the 'Us' usage comes from - could it be a contraction of something like 'Us Americans, we like baseball'?

Comment: @j4nd3r53n That would be its own fascinating philological inquiry. I'm not sure whether there's a connection, but there is a practice of using the object form of pronouns for a compound subject: "Him and me like basketball." There's also a common practice of making the opposite mistake, probably after years of being told "'him and me' is wrong," and using subject pronouns for compound objects: "She gave a presentation to he and I."

Comment: *Hypercorrection* is the term for this type of "opposite mistake".

Comment: It's definitely more "correct," but I suspect that in casual speech it is less used than the "incorrect" version.

Comment: @Casey Actually I'm not so sure (though I have no hard data). I'm in the southern US, and well surrounded by many regional colloquial peculiarities. But while there are many grammatical "mistakes" that I feel like every average person makes on a daily basis, to the point that the "mistake" overtakes the "correct" version, I feel like this isn't one of them. It would sound awkward in the mouth of an "average" man-on-the-street, and I would associate it only with the most extremely rural usages.

Comment: @AndyBonner That's interesting.  I grew up in Connecticut and it's definitely one of those things I mostly consciously scrubbed from my speech at some point... but "we guys like basketball," for instance, still sounds a little pretentious to my ear over "us guys," with the mixed register.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Yes, this exactly. It's older usage, most often found in fictional dialogue.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n  I think the "Us Americans" can arise by application of the "rule":  *Use subject pronouns when the subject **is** the pronoun.  Use object pronouns when the subject **contains** a pronoun with other elements*.  This rule requires you to say "We like baseball" but "Us Americans like baseball" and "Us and those guys like baseball".

Comment: Real™ Americans would say "Us 'mericans like baseball." ;¬)

Comment: @JamesK Ah, I see what you mean - a bit like 'Me Tarzan, ...' ;-)

Answer (score 45):

In these examples, "We Americans" would be the grammatically correct choice because it's the subject. Remove "Americans" from the examples and the choice is clear:

> We like basketball.
> (vs...)
> Us like basketball.

But if it were the object, "us" would be the correct choice:

> Basketball is important to us Americans.

These are the options if you *want* to be strictly grammatically correct, but you might *prefer* a different construction. Many regions, cultures and contexts consistently use constructions that differ from the official grammatical rules, including using "us" with an appositive even in a subject ("Us Americans like basketball"). Language is not a matter of universal moral absolutes, though, so using an "incorrect" construction is not "wrong," especially if it's what's expected and accepted in the context you're in. What's most important is for your intended meaning to be understood. So one might "prefer" "Us Americans [verb]" simply because it's commonly used in their context.

Note, the opposite idiomatic practice doesn't really happen: No one (that I know of) says "Basketball is important to we Americans."

Comment: Actually, I hear a lot of hypercorrection involving "we" and "I" where "us" or "me" would be appropriate. "Please send that memo to Alice and Bob and I" is ubiquitous in business speak. I have taken to saying " to Alice and Bob and to me".

Comment: @CCTO Agreed; I mentioned that in comments on the other answer. Here, I was just noting that you don’t often hear “we” used for an object *in this sort of appositive construction*.

Answer (score 2):

The "us Americans" is partly an assertion of folksiness, or anti-intellectuality, etc. "Just good ol' boys"... yes, with some baggage...

Comment: I wouldn't say that exactly; many people just use it without meaning much of anything by it.  That said, sure, they might meet negative judgment by others for using an "uneducated" form.